# Are questions about RC plane design on topic?

Tags: discussion

I have some questions about designing advanced aerodynamic components for experimental model aircraft. Would these be allowed here?

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8/are-remote-controlled-aircraft-ontopic

Answer (score 6):

The "aerodynamics" aspect would certainly be on-topic here (and we have quite a few folks on the site who could probably help out with that aspect).

The "model aircraft" part is a bit more of a gray area: Most of the questions we have about model aircraft are related to regulations and sharing the airspace, and I'm not sure that questions specifically about building model aircraft are a great fit for the site, but I wouldn't automatically call them off-topic either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, well I'll try out the question, and see how it goes.

Answer (score 5):

They have been generally allowed, as they might fall in the "enthusiast" part of the site:

> site for aircraft pilots, mechanics, and enthusiasts.

Just a friendly heads-up, though: be specific and try to avoid [overly broad questions](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6331), they end up being closed.