# Is the "Autonomous Phantom IV" question on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Link: [Autonomous Phantom IV flight: gimbal and camera control](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42252)

Twice the question was voted off-topic, unanimously. The poster does not agree.

I'm bringing it here for the community's feedback.

P.S. I will not be participating in this discussion any further. Just bringing it to the attention of a wider audience for more feedback.

Comment: in addition to the answers below, we have this precedent meta quesion: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2809

Answer (score 6):

I am one of those that voted to keep the question closed, and in my opinion also the latest iteration of the question

> Is it possible to, using a commercially available off-the-shelf entry level DJI's Phantom IV, pre-establish autonomous flight waypoints AND, simultaneously, gimbal and camera positions and angles at given waypoints?

is still off-topic, because more akin to product support than what we are generally interested here (flight dynamics/aerodynamics/regulations), as it can be derived from which questions with the [unmanned-aerial-vehicle](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unmanned-aerial-vehicle) tag are well received and which are not.

Examples of "product support" questions that got closed:

[Just got a quadcopter, and not sure about a piece that came with it](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/24226/just-got-a-quadcopter-and-not-sure-about-a-piece-that-came-with-it)

[Is a smartphone required to control a DJI Phantom 2 Vision+?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/is-a-smartphone-required-to-control-a-dji-phantom-2-vision)

Comment: Would you feel differently if it had been worded "During autonomous flight with preestablished waypoints, what is the best way to automatize gimbal control"?

Comment: @tonygil no, that's not in scope here. It's even worse, because of the "best way", i.e. opinion based.

Comment: ok, change the "best way" for "an efficient way".  Please understand that I am not trying to strongarm (sorry, forgot that you are not a native english speaker => strongarm = "force someone to do something") youi into accepting my question, I am tring to understand the collective mindset of this community so that my future posts strictly adhere to expectations.  I am, nevertheless, impressed by the virulent reaction you guys seem to have regading UAV's.

Comment: @tonygil "forgot that you are not a native english speaker" if you want people to help you, stop this. have a nice day :)

Answer (score 5):

It is off-topic, clearly being product support request. 
The tag flying technique is incorrect because here we are not talking about a, well, flying technique such as a side-slip, with the explanation being a reasoning about the dynamics of flight or procedures but we are talking about a specific function of a commercial product that has to do solely with the way the product`s coders decided to make it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that hobbyist drone activity, with the wide (and rich) range of associated topics, deserves its own stack exchange board. At the same time, I'd suggest that av.se would do well to establish clear guidance that this forum is NOT about recreational drones, hardware, operating techniques, and etc.

The mainstream of what av.se discusses is simply separate from this sort of drone operation, even though both involve flight and tend to have partially overlapping audiences.

I'm not certain how that distinction would be put into place, but my opinion is that it needs to be.

Comment: currently there is a SE proposal in the early stages: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107036/drones

Answer (score -3):

As the "poster" in question, I understand that a question regarding autonomous flight resources (including standard gimbal control) on a UAV is ON TOPIC because it pertains to the first part of the very first topic listed as germane to this community: `flying technique`.

Even if the question was partially off-topic, it was immediately edited (and then reedited) to achieve maximum / total compliance with community rules.  I understand that, as it stands, it is legitimate.  If not, I apologize for posting a question on flying techniques in a community called Aviation...

The original problem occurred due to the incorrect semantic interpretation of the word "[program](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/program)" by someone whom I suspect to not be a native speaker of the English tongue.  The word firstly means "a public notice" or "outline of the order to be followed" or "plan or system under which action may be taken toward a goal" and was not used as a synonym of "computer coding" (which was what they incorrectly understood and precipitately acted upon).

Comment: You made it clear in [a comment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/42252/autonomous-phantom-iv-flight-gimbal-and-camera-control#comment108443_42252) that that someone is me, as if I cast 5 votes, but as a reminder you wrote in a comment, "There are at least a thousand questions regarding programming and automation in this forum." I really wanted this meta thread to be objective.

Comment: "a question on flying techniques" uh? are you asking how to do a side-slip or how to properly perform an uncommon approach? or how to handle an aircraft while flying in certain conditions?

Comment: Ciao, @Federico. Precisely: I am asking how to preestablish waypoints (firstly if it is even possible to do so) and at the same time preestablish gimbal and camera control.  How is that not `flying technique`?

Comment: "how to preestablish waypoints" -> technical support on a product . "preestablish gimbal and camera control" -> again technical support, nothing to do with people in cockpits and a control stick/column in their hands

Comment: @Federico if you have established waypoints and you give over control to autonomous flight protocols after takeoff, how is that NOT related to the actions at the joystick?  STOP trying to prove that the world is flat.